# Security problem in a asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, eval, spoofing

I am using a button to do postback

```
 <asp:Button ID="SendButton" Enabled="True" Width="70" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("GroupName", "SendMessage.aspx?GroupName={0}") %>' Text='Send'></asp:Button>
```

to send the GroupName to SendMessage.aspx page. But I feel it is vulnerable to attack, something like spoofing (correct me if i am wrong).

http://localhost:40092/SurelyK/SendMessage.aspx?GroupName=Acc

The Url contains the groupname which can be changed by attackers
How can I prevent my website from such attack. give me some suggestions pls.

Comment: Does a user need to be logged in to see this button? Or is it publically accessible

Comment: Did you check browser's view source?

Comment: Yes, the user should be logged in to see the b button.

Comment: How to add eval result to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method to protect against this is to validate your inputs on the server side, where malicious clients can't do anything. If you see an invalid group name on the server, you can just return a page saying so, rather than performing whatever processing you would for a valid group name.

If you don't expect the values to change, then you can store the data either in `ViewState` (which is encrypted) or in the `Session` (which is stored on the server, and is inaccessible to clients.)

Given that you have a button for submitting this information, though, I think proper server-side validation is the correct path.

As well, if you haven't secured this page by requiring authentication and authorization, then you should of course do so as well, so that only users you know and trust can access the page regardless.

Comment: I think he is concerned about the direct url injuction of "GroupName=Acc"

Comment: He said "The Url contains the groupname which can be changed by attackers", which suggest to me that he's concerned about spoofing the name of the group. Validating the group name on the server can prevent that. If there's no such thing as an "invalid" group, then there's no attack here, so that's much of a concern either. Or, if he really is concerned about injection of the whole parameter, that can be validated as well. If a browser can do it, so can a malicious user, so some kind of server-side solution is required.

Comment: How to add eval result to a string. I dont know the format. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Session` variables to hold relevant data instead? Session data persists across multiple pages, until the session ends.

I've never heard of Session variable tempering.